# Recursively adding extensions to files in Windows CMD without renaming the subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, batch-rename

I have a directory with several files that do not have a file extension. This directory also has several subdirectories that have the same thing.

I am using the `forfiles` command to add a file extension. However, when I use this command specifically:

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /c rename @file @fname.ext"
```

It adds the extension to the folders alongside the files.

Is there any way to exclude the subdirectories themselves, only adding the extension to the files in them?

Comment: `forfiles /s /c "cmd /c If "@isdir"=="FALSE" Echo @fname"`

Answer (score 1):

In **PowerShell**, use the `-File` parameter with [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) to retrieve only files. Pipe the output to [`Where-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1) to filter for files with no extension:

```
Get-CHildItem -File -Recurse | Where Extension -like ''
```

Pipe to [`Rename-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-5.1), using a ScriptBlock to construct the new name:

```
Get-CHildItem -File -Recurse | Where Extension -like '' |
   Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name + '.ext' }
```

Key-Banger version:

```
gci -af -recurse | ? Extension -like '' | ren -NewName { $_.Name + '.ext' }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

This can be done more quickly/simply using a simple `for` as suggested on <kbd>**[`ss64.com`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)**</kbd>

- In command line:

```bat
@for /r %i in (*)do @if "" == "%~xi" @ren "%~dpni" "%~ni.log"
```

- In **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**/**[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)** files:

```bat
@echo off
for /r %%i in (*)do if "" == "%%~xi" ren "%%~dpni" "%%~ni.log"
```

1. Loop recursively in your directory tree, get only files from:

```bat
for /r %%i in (*)do
```

2. If the file does not contain (`""`) an extension (`%%~xi`), renamed it using the syntax, providing the full path to the source (`"%%~dpni"`) and only the name (`"%%~ni"`) of the destination adding the desired extension:

```bat
if "" == "%%~xi" ren "%%~dpni" "%~ni.log"
```

When using `forfiles`, for each file queued in the task, cmd is invoked executed and finalized, which results in a loss of performance/time in its processing.

Consider reading the `forfiles` limitations/bugs linked below:

---

- For to the same in **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** files, you can use this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21739887/8177207)** in this question:
  **[How to select files that have no extension using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739178/how-to-select-files-that-have-no-extension-using-powershell)**:

```bat
gci -File -Re | ? {!($_.Extension)}
```

- This command returns to the filtering/recursive listings, only those files that comply with the **`True`** logical condition, where the extension does not exist in your files.

```bat
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | where-object {!($_.Extension)} | Rename-Item -New {$_.basename+'.log'} -Whatif
```

- Or using aliases:

```bat
gci -File -Re | ? {!($_.Extension)} | ren -New {$_.basename+'.log'} -Whatif
```

- You can test and if the results seems zOk to you, just remove **`-Whatif`** for execution...

```bat
gci -File -Re | ? {!($_.Extension)} | ren -New {$_.basename+'.log'} -Whatif
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

  [√] **[ForFiles](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)**

  [√] **[For Loops](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For Loops](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**

  [√] **[Get-Content | cat (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)**

  [√] **[Parameter -Whatif (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-whatif/)**

  [√] **[Rename-Item | ren (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://ss64.com/ps/rename-item.html)**

  [√] **[ForEach-Object | ? (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)**

  [√] **[Concatenate items in variable list (Refer: `PowerShell`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802153/8177207)** By **[@Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)**

---